# including $book->author in echo ""

Tags: php, echo

I'm trying to print $book->author in an echo statement. Right now I'm using concatenation.

```
echo "book author: " . $book->author . "<br />";
```

How can I include the whole thing in double quotes? If I do the following, it assumes I'm trying to echo the `$book` object and that `->author` is a regular string.

```
echo "book author: $book->author<br />";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in curly braces.

```
echo "book author: {$book->author}<br />";
```

As an aside, I'm an advocate of the following. I find it reads better, overcomes limitations of the curly brace approach, and <strike>is a *micro*, *micro* optimization over string concatenation</strike> (see comments).

```
echo "book author: ", $book->author, "<br />";
```

Comment: does the same thing work with `object->method()` like `$book->getAuthor()` or `$book->getAuthor($param)`

Comment: Good question. I know my second example does. Hence, why I'm a fan.

Comment: @thirdender, thanks for the clarification. I will run some tests. As I said, if it is, it's *micro micro*. The fact that it reads better for me far outweighs any performance gain.

Comment: [PHP String: Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) I read this wrong the first time. I really hate PHP :-p The `{$}` syntax can be used to get a variable with the same name as a function's return value, but not the return value itself… I'm at a loss why that would ever be something you'd want to do. Getting a function's return value seems like a much more logical choice.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary thanks for testing :-p I got lazy just short of testing it myself. PHP double-quotes are weirdly optimized to a level above the rest of the code. I think it might be a throwback from the language's "PHP as a HTML template system" roots (from the days when PHP was only used for substituting variables into HTML pages, and wasn't veneered as a language for writing complex applications). Also, even though `echo "Monkeys", " and bananas\n";` works fine, the same statement using `print` throws `syntax error, unexpected ','`, which drives me nuts.